# How to handle XMLhttpRequest.Response based alerts without time violation?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, response, alert

What I have:

A Form with file attachment that on submit gets send via `XMLhttpRequest` (in JSON) to an external server. I get a response, and the user gets an alert window if the data has been submitted - or what information is missing.

Problem:

However chrome is not too happy with it, because apparently the `window.alert` in the `readystate == 4` is not a good idea?

The `ms` from the error message seem to be the time the user takes to click OK.
See error message below:

```
[Violation] 'readystatechange' handler took 3203ms
```

This is the code in question:

```
abc.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (abc.readyState == 4) {
    var answer = abc.response;
    if (answer.success) {
     // alert("Data was sent. Number: " + answer.Number);
      console.log("Data was sent. Number: " + answer.Number);
    }
    else {
      //alert("Data is missing: " + answer.message);
      console.log("Data is missing: " + answer.message);
    }
  }
};
```

What is the  better way to use different `window.alert` based on the values of the `.response` ?

Comment: How does it go with `console.log` instead of `alert`? Also check the code you have posted, there seem to a *closing brace* `}` missing?

Comment: changed code a bit so it's more understandable. I commented out the `alert` and added `console.log`, no warning this time.

Comment: before your first if, can you put this statement and share the output `console.log(abc.readyState)`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a generic violation warning message thrown by chrome to report those functions which are taking too long

As per this [thread](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/3tViQmRF2l8/discussion)

> **Summary**
>
> A new performance API to enable applications to detect presence of
>   “long tasks” that monopolize the UI thread for extended periods of
>   time and block other critical tasks from being executed - e.g.
>   reacting to user input.

Going by the message you have received, it looks like chrome has thrown a *warning that you took 3 seconds to close the alert box*.

Also,

- This is just a warning, **you can hide this warning** by choosing log levels 
  in your *developer tool's console*.
- Use `console.log` for debugging, instead of `alert`.